# Mysql Table - CREATE COLUMN that compares values of other columns?

Tags: mysql, boolean, create-table, sqldatatypes

could not find anythig on the web or Mysql documentation. I have a table and want the last column to show a true/false statement:

if (value_x === value_y)

Is that possible?

```
id | value_x | value_y | check_xy
---------------------------------
01 |       10|       10|     true
02 |       11|       44|    false
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key, value_x int, value_y int);

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 10, 10), (2, 11, 44);

mysql> alter table mytable add column check_xy bool as (value_x = value_y);

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+---------+---------+----------+
| id | value_x | value_y | check_xy |
+----+---------+---------+----------+
|  1 |      10 |      10 |        1 |
|  2 |      11 |      44 |        0 |
+----+---------+---------+----------+
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html for more information.

Note this is a feature introduced in MySQL 5.7. If you use an older version of MySQL, you'll have to upgrade first.